# Discrete Topology definition question

Tags: general-topology, complex-numbers

Definition: The topology in which every set is open (and therefore every set is closed).

So is the set of complex numbers a discrete topology?

Comment: No, a thousand times no.

Comment: why? The set of all complex numbers is open and closed

Comment: Is *every* set of complex numbers open and closed? For example, the set $\{1+0i\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work. The definition of discrete topology is that every **subset** of $X$ be open, and consequently closed. While it's true that $\mathbb{C}$ is both open and closed, we can build subsets thereof that are only open or only closed (or neither!). An easy example is the unit ball $\{ z : |z| < 1\}$, open but certainly not closed!